# proc template color loess by group

Tags: sas, loess, sas-gtl

I am trying to set the colors for the lines generated by proc template by group.

```
PROC TEMPLATE;
 Define statgraph LOESS_BAR;
 begingraph;
   Layout Lattice/ columns=1 columnweights=(1) ;
     Layout overlay/ xaxisopts=(griddisplay=off Label = 'Days' Linearopts=viewmin=-90 viewmax=365 tickvaluesequence=(start=-390 end=390 increment=30)))
           yaxisopts=(griddisplay=off label= 'Score' linearopts=(viewmin=0 viewmax=100));
        loessplot x=days y=measure /group=groupnm index=rank smooth=0.5 name='LOESS';
     ENDlayout;
 EndLayout;
endgraph;
end;
run;
```

My data has the columns:

Days - days from the event (x-axis)

Measure - the data points being used for the LOESS curve (y-axis)

MarkerColor - the color I would like to use for the line

groupnm - distinguishes the groups to generate each line

Comment: Did you have a question for us or are you looking for a cheerleader? Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: You maybe better off using a Discrete attribute map. I would check how that works using an SGPLOT procedure and generating the template code from there.